# "InvalidOperation: (op_Addition:String) [], RuntimeException" in Powershell

Tags: powershell

I have a script that works on other PCs. It only on one PC I have following error message.

Error:
Fehler beim Aufrufen der Methode, da [System.Object[]] keine Methode mit dem Namen "op_Addition" enthält.
In C:\Users\stream1\Desktop\watchdog.ps1:8 Zeichen:5

- ```
  $wmi += (Get-WMIObject -Class Win32_PerfFormattedData_Tcpip_Netwo ...
  ```
- ```
  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  ```

  - CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (op_Addition:String) [], RuntimeException
  - FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodNotFound

Thats the script:

```
#$ErrorActionPreference = 'SilentlyContinue'
$threshold = 6000
$timer = new-timespan -Seconds 10
$wmi = 0
$count = 0
$clock = [diagnostics.stopwatch]::StartNew()
while ($clock.elapsed -lt $timer){
    $wmi += (Get-WMIObject -Class Win32_PerfFormattedData_Tcpip_NetworkInterface | Select-Object BytesSentPerSec).BytesSentPerSec
    $count++
}

$kbytes = ($wmi/$count)  / 1kb * 8 #to kbit/s 


if($kbytes -le $threshold)
{
    Write-Output $kbytes
    Write-Host "Neustart"
    taskkill /f /im obs64.exe
    timeout /t 5
    Start-Process -FilePath "obs64.exe" -WorkingDirectory "C:\Program Files\obs-studio\bin\64bit\" --startstreaming --minimize-to-tray
}
else    
{
    Write-Output $kbytes
    Write-Host "Alles OK"
}
```

Does somebody has any idea?
Thanks so much :-)

I thought it was due to the permission to run scripts in Powershell. But I allowed the execution of scripts (Unrestricted)

Comment: `$wmi = @()` (start with an empty array) but in general, you should [try to avoid using the increase assignment operator (`+=`) to create a collection](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60708579/1701026)

Comment: Thank you for your answer :-)
so I should change "$wmi = 0" to "$wmi = @()"?

Now I have this message:
Fehler beim Aufrufen der Methode, da [System.Object[]] keine Methode mit dem Namen "op_Division" enthält.
In C:\Users\stream1\Desktop\watchdog.ps1:12 Zeichen:1
+ $kbytes = ($wmi/$count)  / 1kb * 8 #to kbit/s
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (op_Division:String) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodNotFound

------------------------
Sorry, I have no idea about programming. Someone wrote me the script.

Comment: ```Get-WMIObject -Class Win32_PerfFormattedData_Tcpip_NetworkInterface``` returns multiple objects if you have multiple network cards so you need to decide if you want to filter it to a specific card, or whether you ant to add up the ```BytesSentPerSec``` for al the cards together. At the moment  youre doing ```(gwmi ..).BytesSentPerSec``` which returns an *array* with a value for each network card. If you want to add them you can do ```$wmi += ((Get-WMIObject -Class Win32_PerfFormattedData_Tcpip_NetworkInterface).BytesSentPerSec | measure-object -Sum).Sum```...

Comment: Thank you :-)
Now I get this:
"Fehler beim Aufrufen der Methode, da [System.Object[]] keine Methode mit dem Namen "op_Division" enthält.
In C:\Users\stream1\Desktop\watchdog.ps1:12 Zeichen:1
+ $kbytes = ($wmi/$count)  / 1kb * 8 #to kbit/s
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (op_Division:String) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodNotFound"